# Any way to make stored procedure code dynamically reference other databases, without dynamic sql?

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql, synonyms

I've a situation where I have two databases:

- ABCData
- ABCUsers

One of the stored procedures in ABCData needs to perform an insert to a table in ABCUsers. This could just be hard coded:

```
INSERT ABCUsers.dbo.Table1 VALUES('a');
```

But the next problem we run into is that we want to backup and redeploy these database pairs to similarly named other databases for testing and dev purposes:

- XYZData
- XYZUsers

Which means the XYZData database will contain a sproc that doesn't work - because the insert has a hard coded `ABCUsers.dbo.Table1`, and we don't want to get into changing it

We could find out the current database name in the sproc, adjust it and run the sql dynamically:

```
DECLARE @DataDbName sysname = (DB_NAME());
DECLARE @UserDBName NVARCHAR(20) = (SELECT REPLACE(@DataDbName, 'Data', 'Users'));
EXEC CONCAT('INSERT ', @UserDbName, '.dbo.Table1 VALUES(''a'');')
```

But I think the prospect of doing so actually makes me feel physically ill ;) (not least because this is a massively simplified example of tens of sprocs each making tens of calls to other dbs)

Is there a way to alias a database name during its creation, so the sproc can always say something like:

```
INSERT UserDbAlias.dbo.Table1 VALUES('a');
```

And when the `ABCUsers` database is created, the `UserDbAlias -> ABCUsers` but when `XYZUsers` db is created `UserDbAlias -> XYZUsers`

---

Alternatively, this is a git/tfs source control - is there a way to write the source control version of the sproc so that it is modified dynamically when it's deployed, and the original source can contain some kind of placeholder for the db names, but they're replaced with actual hard coded varying db names upon deploy (automatically)

---

Footnotes: I looked at [A way to reference other DB without hardcoding its name](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/179575/a-way-to-reference-other-db-without-hardcoding-its-name) which does seem to describe my problem, but doesn't have an answer. That question mentioned "I've looked at synonyms but they wouldn't work out with EF6.." (paraphrase)

Would synonyms work out for me? We use EF6, but I'm not sure what the actual problem is in terms of why it wouldn't work out. Our sproc name in the db never changes, and we don't need to alias the sproc itself, it's the insert table name we need to alias. If the sproc is always called `Sproc1` regardless of whether it's in `ABCData` or `XYZData`, and the synonym resolving happens inside the sproc, would EF6 even have a problem with it?

Comment: why do you need to change the DB names? You mention "testing and dev" but you don't mention having multiple copies in prod for different customers (or whatever the difference would be). Why not just keep the same name on the dev _and_ testing servers?

Comment: The test server might have 20+ database pairs on it

Comment: how big are these DBs?...and how big do you see them getting over the next year or two?

Comment: The dev ones are typically small; contain a pared down set of info from prod. Prod is huge, hundreds of gb

Comment: The number and size of them will probably vary considerably; deployed via script for a particular purpose, populated (by removing some amount of data), used and removed..

Comment: Have you considered using multiple instances of Developer Edition? It is free starting in SQL Server 2016, SP1 and I believe that using it for testing / dev / QA would be within the confines of the license. The idea would be to spin up N number of instaces that you retores the DBs into and never change the DB names...just the connection strings....If this will work, I can post it as an answer.. The instance name can even contain the client ID or some identifier to make it programmatically discoverable.

Comment: Pretty sure the DBAs are more wedded to the idea of one sqls enterprise instance with multiple DBs because they was to script the creating of a new db and I don't know if there's scope for scripting the install of a new sqls instance. I had a play with synonyms and it seems to work out; they also seem creatable with dynamic sql so can dynamically reference a different database, and if the database creation is scripted I don't see why the synonym creation cannot also be. Are you aware of any drawbacks to using synonyms?

Comment: Why waste an enterprise license on a testing instance when dev edition is free? Unattended install of instance should be fairly easy, else it is a good scenario for a virtual box VMs (which can be scripted to copy and rename) or containers. Even if synonyms appear to work, it's not a good test as you are changing the environment and there could be anomalies introduced or unintended consequences that will require additional time to work around.

Comment: All good questions; I'm not the DBA so I can't answer them directly. I asked this question as a voyage of discovery as to how one might safely address a foreign database whose name can be derived from knowledge of the local database name. I raised the point that synonyms could be used for this, and I've been told "we don't like synonyms, use dynamic sql", which I feel offers massive drawbacks for code security, readability, maintainability. I can imagine how "why don't we install separate SQLS instances then?" would go down, but I agree with your perspective and see it as a useful alternative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from design considerations raised in the comments, ...

Consider one level of indirection prior to creation of the stored procedure:

- write a template for the stored procedure, with token placeholders for the schema names

`INSERT DBNAMETOKEN.dbo.Table1 VALUES('a');`

- write a pre-deployment script (sed?) that creates a new file  specifically for each schema, substituting the actual schema name for the token.
- place resulting scripts in per-schema deployment directories, from which they may be installed as usual.

#### Benefits

- Scales well
- Both template and custom versions may be under version control
- Updates/Fixes may still be deployed through a single change to the template file and propagated through a build step
- Possibly easier to schedule/track deployment of updates to each schema  depending on situation
- Reduces the stored procedure to a simple(r) set of SQL focussed on the task at hand, rather than the dynamics of making it work across different schema.